# Split rails form into smaller forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have a User model set up with devise and a Profile model. User has_one profile and profile belongs to a user.

The profile form is very long taking in 10+ fields, what I'm looking to do is create a side bar with links to smaller sections of the profile model.

For example the profile model takes perusal details, so have a link to personal details, when the user clicks personal details, he can enter personal details, and a link for address and when user clicks address the address form pops up. All these sub forms would essentially build the profile model.

At the moment when the user is created the profile is built along with the user and is connected accordingly.

What is the best way to getting this done?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, overall. Did you have a specific question?

Comment: My question is how would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to create separate controllers for each of the sections. So, you might have a `PersonalDetailsController`, `AddressesController`, and so on.

My practice, then, is to create a plain old Ruby object that I name consistently with the controllers. So, I would have a `PersonalDetailsManager`, `AddressesManager`, and so on. These 'managers` (some people call them 'services') might look something like this:

```
  # app/managers/personal_details_manager.rb
  class PersonalDetailsManager
    class << self
      def create_details(params)
        ... logic to create new personal details
      end

      def update_details(params)
        ... logic to update personal details
      end
    end
  end
```

In my managers, I always return a hash. If the operation was successful, the hash will include `success: true`. And, I usually include a `body` element that contains any information that (a) the controller will need for any post processing or (b) the view may need for rendering. I often include an `errors` element in case I want to use that for feedback to the user.

Note that I put the managers in their own folder. Then, in my controller, I might do something like:

```
  PersonalDetailsController < ApplicationController
    def create
      @results = PersonalDetailsManager.create_details(params)
      if @results[:success]
        ... do success routing and/or post processing
      else
        ... do failure routing and/or post processing
      end
    end
  end
```

Some things I like about this approach:

1. It creates very loose coupling between my view, controllers and
   models.
2. It's way easier to test POROs than to test controllers,
   IMO.
3. You can use the managers to manage transactions across
   multiple models (using, potentially, actual transaction blocks to
   manage failed model interactions).
4. Depending on your requirements, you can use the managers across controllers and maintain transparency about where methods are coming from.